# How to create an asyncpg pool that sets codecs (type converters) automatically?

Tags: python, async-await, type-conversion, asyncpg

More specifically, I need to use `hstore`, `json` an `jsonb` values. There are built-in codecs for this, but they must be registered on the connection explicitly, as described in https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html#example-decoding-hstore-values

```py
import asyncpg
import asyncio

async def run():
    conn = await asyncpg.connect()
    # Assuming the hstore extension exists in the public schema.
    await conn.set_builtin_type_codec(
        'hstore', codec_name='pg_contrib.hstore')
    result = await conn.fetchval("SELECT 'a=>1,b=>2,c=>NULL'::hstore")
    assert result == {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': None}

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run())
```

Since I need these codec everwhere in my application, I want to create a pool that automatically sets these codecs when a **new** connection is created.

But I'm not sure how to do this. I can see that `connection_class` can be given for `create_pool`. In other words, I can create a pool that uses a custom connection class, for example:

```py
async def create_my_pool(pool_config):
    return await asyncpg.create_pool(connection_class=MyDbConnection, **pool_config)
```

But it does not solve the problem, because I cannot call `set_builtin_type_codec` from `MyDbConnection.__init__`, simply because `set_builtin_type_codec` is an async method, and the constructor of my custom `MyDbConnection` is not async.

I might be able to write my own async context manager that wraps the one that is returned by `asyncpg.create_pool`, but then I need to keep track of each connection and set the codecs on them only if they have not been set previously. It looks very clumsy.

Since this problem (e.g. automatically setting codecs) seems to be a very common requirement to me, there must be a better way to do this, I just can't figure it out.

So this is my question: how to create an asyncpg pool that sets various codecs automatically, whenever if creates a **new** connection?

Answer (score 1):

First, we create our own connection class, that has a codec installer:

```py
import copy
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

import asyncpg
import asyncpg.pool

class MyConnection(asyncpg.Connection):
    _codecs_installed = False

    async def _install_codecs(self):
        if not self._codecs_installed:
            await self.set_builtin_type_codec('hstore', codec_name='pg_contrib.hstore')
            # install more codecs here...
            self._codecs_installed = True
```

The key point is that a connection can be reused by the pool (re-acquired by the users of the pool), but the codecs are installed once per connection.

Then we create a wrapper that mimics `asyncpg.Pool` (has an acquire method), but asks the connection to install the codecs (if they are not already installed):

```py
class Db:
    def __init__(self, db_config):
        self._db_config = db_config
        self._pool = None

    async def initialize(self):
        self._pool = await asyncpg.pool.create_pool(connection_class=MyConnection, **self._db_config)

    @asynccontextmanager
    async def acquire(self, timeout=None) -> MyConnection:
        async with self._pool.acquire(timeout=timeout) as conn:
            await conn._install_codecs()
            yield conn
```

This is clumsy, because in production code, you need to wrap all `Pool` methods, and re-wrap them whenever the signature(s) of `asyncpg.Pool` methods are changed. **Please note that it is not possible to simply subclass asyncpg.Pool, because `asyncpg.Pool.acquire` is NOT an async method.**

And finally, define a `create_pool` function that should be used instead of `asyncpg.create_pool`:

```py
async def create_pool(**db_config):
    db = Db(db_config=db_config)
    await db.initialize()
    return db
```

This solution actually works, but I still think that there must be a better way.